# Sum of sizes of subsets which intersect at most one element

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, solution-verification, discrete-geometry

I have the following problem at hand (HW problem so please don't give me full solutions).
We have a set $N$ with $n$ elements and $M=\{M_1,M_2,\dots,M_n\}$ such that each two intersect at at most one element. I am asked to ddetermine weather $\sum(|M_i|)= O(n^{4/3})$. My claim is that it is and I show it in the following way:

Place the points of $N$ in plane in such a way that points of $M_i$ are colinear, then construct a set of $n$ lines $L=\{l_1,\dots,l_n\}$ where $l_i$ correspond to $M_i$. Then $\sum(|M_i|)$ is exactly the number of incidences between $L$ and $N$ so by Szemeredi-Trotter we're done.

Is this the correct approach or do I need to change something?

Comment: **Hint:** Each set $M_i$ contains $\binom{|M_i|}2$ pairs of points, and each of the $\binom{n}2$ pairs of points only appears in at most one of the $M_i$. This gives you an inequality involving $M_i$. Use convexity to manipulate this inequality.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I am not sure if I understand your idea. The fact about pairs tels us $\sum \binom{|M_i|}{2} \le \binom{n}{2}$, right? Further, $\sum O(|M_i|^2) \le O(n^2)$. Am I correct and/or close to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My previous version of this answer consisted of hints that were misleading*.

You cannot prove that $\sum_i |M_i|$ is $O(n^{4/3})$. In the case where there exists a projective plane with $n$ points, and we let $M_i$ be the set of points on the $i^\text{th}$ line, then you would have $\sum_i |M_i|\in \Theta(n^{3/2})$. Precisely, when $n=q^2+q+1$ for some prime power $q$, then a projective plane exists, where each $|M_i|=q+1$, and each point is contained in $q+1$ lines/sets.

Regarding your attempted proof, this must mean that it is not always possible to realize the given list of sets as an incidence system of points and lines in the plane.

Comment: Jansen's inequality is game so I like the first approach but it is still confusing me as to how this gives me a bound. When I apply $f$ to $1/n\sum_{i=1}^n|M_1|$ I am getting $1/2n^2 \sum|M_i|)^2 - 1/2n(\sum |M_i)$ and then dividing by $1/n$ on both sides of Jensen's inequality and rework it I get $1/2\sum|M_i| \ge 1/2n \sum|M_i| - \sum \binom{|M_i|}{2}$ and that is sort of a useless lower bound? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I have led you astray, sorry! When you complete the proof as I said, you only get $$\binom n2\ge \sum_i \binom{|M_i|}2=n\cdot \frac1n\sum_i \binom{|M_i|}2\stackrel{\text{Jensen}}\ge n\cdot \binom{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n |M_i|}{2}\ge n\cdot \frac12\left(-1+\sum_{i=1}^n |M_i|\right)^2$$ which only gets you $O(n^{3/2})$, not $O(n^{4/3})$. In fact, this is the best you can do, because you can concoct set systems which achieve $O(n^{3/2})$. Namely, projective planes. I am ashamed I did not think of this sooner...

Comment: Thank you dor the help anyways @MikeEarnest! This makes it much clearer